# Validate xml via dtd, different directory for dtd

Tags: c#, xml, xml-validation, dtd

I am trying to validate an xml file via a .dtd. I have write this validator:

```
    public bool Validation(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        var xml = XmldocToString(xmlDoc);
        var r = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml));
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += (a, e) =>
        {
            sb.AppendLine(e.Message);
            _isValid = false;
        };
        XmlReader validator = XmlReader.Create(r, settings);
        while (validator.Read())
        {
        }
        validator.Close();

        return _isValid;
    }
```

The problem is that I must have the dtd file in bin directory of the Solution. I want to chose a diferent directory to keep the .dtd file and i really can't find how.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare in the Xml file the association with the DTD:

### Example in case the dtd is stored in a remote server:

```
<!DOCTYPE Catalog PUBLIC "abc/Catalog" "http://xyz.abc.org/dtds/catalog.dtd">
```

Take a look at that [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition#Associating_DTDs_with_documents) and at [that site](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dstudio/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user/topics/cxmlcat.html) for more options and information about Xml files and DTD association.

### Example in case the dtd is placed locally (SYSTEM):

> **How to reference a DTD from a document**:
>
> Assuming the top element of the document is **spec** and the dtd is placed
>   in the **file mydtd in the subdirectory dtds of the directory from where
>   the document were loaded**:

```
<!DOCTYPE spec SYSTEM "dtds/mydtd">
```

> **Notes**:
>
> The system string is actually an URI-Reference (as defined in RFC
>   2396) so you can use a full URL string indicating the location of your
>   DTD on the Web. This is a really good thing to do if you want others
>   to validate your document. It is also possible to associate a PUBLIC
>   identifier (a magic string) so that the DTD is looked up in catalogs
>   on the client side without having to locate it on the web. A DTD
>   contains a set of element and attribute declarations, but they don't
>   define what the root of the document should be. This is explicitly
>   told to the parser/validator as the first element of the DOCTYPE
>   declaration.

(Excerpt from [**here**](http://www.xmlsoft.org/xmldtd.html))

Comment: The expected dtd stored in xml files would be something like this:

<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd">

Do you mean i shoud redirect the dtd call,by altering the xml files?

Comment: Thank you for your time. 
But i don't want to validate my documents but documents of others, so i would prefer to avoid altering them. I was hoping of being able to tweak the parser/validator to get the DTD from the directory i prefer.

Comment: Now the xml file is in the same dir of the DTD, the "bin" dir, correct? If so, can you move both the files to the other dir you prefer?

Comment: Another idea is to put a symbolic link in the bin dir for the tmx14.dtd file, and place the actual file wherever you want.