# C# Validate XML file using a DTD file without the DOCTYPE string

Tags: c#, xml, validation, dtd

I am trying to write a C# class that validates a xml file using a DTD file located in another folder that is not in a relative location with the DOCTYPE string, so far, my code is like this:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
            settings.XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(IsLoaded);

            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString), settings))
            {
                while (reader.Read()) { }
                reader.Close();
            }
```

So far this works fine loading the DTD file from the DOCTYPE string included in the xml file, but the DTD file itself must be kept in a folder that is relative to where the program is being excuted. Is there a way to mingle with the XmlResolver class where I can ask it to get a DTD file from another location on my hard drive, like an absoute path being passed in the find the DTD files instead of using the DOCTYPE string?

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13310387/2779990

Comment: So, from what I have read, the xml validator must use the DTD location specified in the DOCTYPE string, and I have to somehow change the DOCTYPE string to represent the location of my DTD files, is that correct?

Comment: Correct, but you may not have that option in the Settings object.  Could you host your DTD via an URL?  If not could copy the DTD files to same folder that the DOCTYPE refs before processing?  Or could you update the DOCTYPE in the xml file prior to processing it using a string replace (not sure if that's the best option tho)